# Cocos Creator - orientation change event in native build for iPhone and Android

Tags: cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-js

I am making some Hybrid app which has some native part in Both iOS and Android and common functionality (which includes and games/animation and UI) which I make in Cocos Creator.

The problem I am facing while I am trying to change the device orientaiton from Portrait to Landscape of vice-versa.

I tried to get the current frame size or get notified about the change, but no success.

Anyone face this issue? Any ideas are welcome!

Answer (score 1):

Hi I have develop a game for iOS, android and for browser and I have used this code to get sizes of my device.

```
console.log("Game Manager onLoad called", cc.winSize.width, cc.winSize.height,cc.director.getVisibleSize().width);

console.log("OS NAME ", cc.sys.os);
console.log("Platform NAME ", cc.sys.platform);
```

this may help you.